# what is the following regular expression trying to match?

Tags: regex, tcl

I saw a re like this:

```
regexp "hello\[^\\n]*06" $str
```

what is the `\[^\\n]*` trying to match?

Comment: Are you sure about the "\"  before the "[" ? It's strange. It looks like an error.

Comment: It must be a typo or a troll attempt, It should be `[^\\n]*` which means match anything except `\n` (line feed) zero or more times.

Comment: I am sure there is a "\" before the "["

Comment: @user2131316 Well do you need it ? What would you like to match ? Developers are humans, they can make mistakes. Anyways it doesn't make sense.

Comment: hello HamZa, I read the code above, I do not understand how it is going to match

Comment: It matches anything BUT '\n' (not a line feed, an explicit '\' + 'n').

If you can give some context someone might be able to discover the motivation behind it. Edit: the '\' before '[' is very peculiar as was stated. This seems like an error.

Comment: It's tcl. Square brackets in tcl perform command substitution just like backticks do in bash. So yes, the `\[` is necessary to avoid the language complaining about `command '^' not found`

Comment: @slebetman If that is true, then why is the closing bracket not escaped `\]` ?

Comment: @HamZa: It's not necessary since a closing bracket does not have any significant meaning to the language without the opening bracket.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In tcl, strings grouped by double quotes (`""`) undergo substitution when evaluated. As you know, tcl understands the following substitutions:

- variable substututions: Any word that starts with the `$` sign is substituted for its value.
- command substutution: Any group of words between `[` and `]` is treated as a statement and the first word is called as a command (function).
- escape substitution: Any backslash (`\`) is treated as an escape sequence and substituted accordingly.

Therefore, the following code:

```
regexp "hello\[^\\n]*06" $str
```

is equivalent to:

```
regexp {hello[^\n]*06} $str
```

So it's trying to match the string that contains the word "hello" and "06" without any newlines between them.